# ngx-socket-io with token form ionic local Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io, ionic4

I'm build an **ionic realTime chat app** and using the **ngx-socket-io package**.
and I have a token that I already stored it in local storage, I can't get the token value from local storage in **app.module.ts**
this my code

```
import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/', options: {
  query: {
    token: myToken
  }
}};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    FormPage,ChatPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    AutosizeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,FormPageModule,ChatPageModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

So how can i import  myToken variable from local storage

Answer (score 2):

To solve after you get your token from localStorage you can set the params before connecting

```
this.socket.ioSocket.io.opts.query = { token } 
this.socket.connect();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get it like this

```
localStorage.getItem("key-with-which-you-stored-your-token")
```